# Issue with firing event KeyDown on TextBox when it's 'jumping' to a TextBox WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grid, keydown

I have a Grid which contains like few TextBoxes below each other :

[image]

By pressing Enter I need to jump from txt1 to txt2, from txt2 to txt3 and so on, and I solved it like this:

```
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            UIElement element = e.Source as UIElement;

            element.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            //e.Handled = true;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And my issue is here, on each of txt boxes by pressing Enter I should calculate something from another txtBoxes, and when I press enter on txt1 it is gonna jump on txt2 and immediatelly call `txt2_KeyDown` event, which I want to avoid.. I want to call `txt2_KeyDown` event when I'm 'standing' on txt2 and when I press enter..

i.e:

```
private void txt2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        try
        {

            CalculateSomethingFromOtherTextBoxes();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This above is being fired when I am 'standing' on txt1 and when I want to jump to txt2 by pressing Enter, how can I just 'jump' without calling txt2 KeyDown event If I did not press Enter while I am really 'standing' on 'txt2'.

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: Maybe you can create new helper variable? I mean, if you are setting focus to next, set this variable to true. In txt2 keydown check, if its true, set  this variable to false and also put return. I don't know for now any other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And my issue is here, on each of txt boxes by pressing Enter I should calculate something from another txtBoxes, and when I press enter on txt1 it is gonna jump on txt2 and immediatelly call txt2_KeyDown event, which I want to avoid.. I want to call txt2_KeyDown event when I'm 'standing' on txt2 and when I press enter..

Then you could handle the `LostKeyboardFocus` event of "txt2" instead of handling the `KeyDown` event:

```
private Key key;
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    key = e.Key;
    if (key == Key.Enter)
    {
        UIElement element = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        element.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }

}

private void txt2_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (key == Key.Enter)
    {
        CalculateSomethingFromOtherTextBoxes();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code inside "txt2_LostKeyboardFocus" will never be executed. On LostKeyboardFocus event, how can you check for "Enter" hit?

Comment: Of course you need to hook up the event handler. I store the last pressed key in the key field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of a `KeyDown` event that you attached to textboxes.

Instead, remove this event and add `PreviewKeyDown` event.

So, your method signature should be something like this:

```
private void txt2_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            try
            {

               CalculateSomethingFromOtherTextBoxes();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

I tested it and it is working as expected.

Comment: can you explain it little bit more? It is fired because I attached KeyDown event on my TextBoxes and When element.MoveFocus is triggered it is immediatelly firing KeyDown because I created it and put some code inside?

Comment: KeyDown event is bubbling event whereas PreviewKeyDown is tunneling event. You can search more about these events.

Comment: When we use PreviewKeyDown  event, it is first handled by, in our case "Grid" and after that, it goes to textbox's event handler. Consider current use case. You hit "Enter" on textbox1. First it will go to "Grid" and after that, it will come to textbox 1's handler. So event of textbox 2 will not be raised, becaue this event was originally raised by textbox 1. I hope, this clears your doubt.